# Duplicate values when using pluck with localization I18n / globalize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using pluck to get a list of all the categories I have in my app with the localised translation (I'm using I18n and globalize gem)

```rb
Category.order(:name).pluck(:name, :id)
```

I get something like the following results when my app is using the French locale

```
[["Banking", 3],  ["Bancaire", 3], ["Electric scooter", 10], ["Trottinette éléctrique", 10], ["Travel", 12], ["Voyage", 12]....
```

When my locale is set to English I only have the english values but when I'm using a different locale I have both the english version and the localized one. 
How could I get only the locale results (FYI: I'm putting this results inside a select)

Comment: What DB query is generated? What values are in the database?

Comment: ```SELECT "categories"."id", "categories"."slug", "categories"."created_at", "categories"."updated_at" FROM "categories"``` and for each item in the db ```SELECT category_translations.name, "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "category_translations" ON "category_translations"."category_id" = "categories"."id" WHERE "category_translations"."locale" = $1 ORDER BY "category_translations"."name" ASC```

Comment: What's `$1` in that query? Is it possible you've actually stored English *and* French translations under the `fr` locale?

Comment: Sorry I got the query from the english locale here is the one when i'm using french ```SELECT DISTINCT category_translations.name, "categories"."id" FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "category_translations" ON "category_translations"."category_id" = "categories"."id" WHERE "category_translations"."locale" IN ($1, $2) ORDER BY "category_translations"."name" ASC  [["locale", "fr"], ["locale", "en"]]```

Comment: Maybe you should ask at the github project of globalize (for example https://github.com/globalize/globalize/issues/427). It looks like the gem is doing a lot of things under the hood

Comment: @user3805610 Ah, in that case it seems to be a gem issue rather than a data issue. Which version of ruby/rails/globalize are you using? Can you create a minimal reproduction example? If it's all up-to-date, and your reproduction doesn't do anything weird, perhaps raise an issue with the library maintainers.

Comment: Ok I found a fix, the error was coming from the way I was creating the select. I was using form_for which was creating duplicate. When I create the form through a for loop it's only showing the localized results. Thanks for you help guys